# Excel: Find lowest value that has boolean in second column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513391/excel-find-first-lowest-value-in-range-determined-by-a-second-column), which is very much like my problem, but there's a twist, and I'm not sure how to do what I specifically need.

I have two columns, one for the date and one containing a boolean "TRUE/FALSE". The date is formatted as an excel date. I would like to find the first and last date that has a boolean "TRUE". Ideally I'd like to solve the problem without resorting to VBA macros.

The twist when compared tot the [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513391/excel-find-first-lowest-value-in-range-determined-by-a-second-column) is that I want to find the lowest value of the date, not the number of people in his example. I would also like to not need to sort the table, because the "TRUE" and "FALSE" will be changing due to other (manually changeable) factors, for which sorting the list (16k+ rows) each time you make a change would take too much time.

Date - Bool
14-5 - FALSE
15-5 - TRUE
16-5 - FALSE
01-6 - FALSE
20-6 - TRUE
17-5 - FALSE
18-5 - TRUE
19-5 - TRUE

Note that the list is *not* sorted on date

Result should be:
First: 15-5
Last: 20-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simply with array formulas.  Array formula are entered by holding down **ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you do it correctly, in the formula bar you will see that Excel placed braces **{...}** around the formula:

```
=MIN(IF(Bool,Dates))
=MAX(IF(Bool,Dates))
```

Where Bool and Dates are the named ranges of the designated columns.

Comment: That was... rather simple! Thank you very much for this answer!